# Infopath in sharepoint issues with validation

Tags: c#, validation, sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-2013

I have been moving a bunch of infopath forms (many created in infopath 2003) to SharePoint using info path 2013.

One of the features of the way we have been doing forms for years is to allow the user to save their progress in filling out the form. In infopath we pull this off by checking for validation errors, if there are in why set a node in the xml that indicates that the form isn't complete, save and clear the errors, call the save webservice and then put the errors back by simply setting the value that each node with a validation error with the value it already has.

Examples:
Check for errors:

```
XPathNavigator node =      MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("//my:reportIsValid", NamespaceManager);
if (Errors.Count == 0)
            node.SetValue("1");
        else
            node.SetValue("0");
```

Save and clear errors:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<FormError> SaveErrors = new System.Collections.Generic.List<FormError>();
SaveErrors.AddRange(Errors.GetErrors(FormErrorType.SchemaValidation));
SaveErrors.AddRange(Errors.GetErrors(FormErrorType.SystemGenerated));
SaveErrors.AddRange(Errors.GetErrors(FormErrorType.UserDefined));


Errors.DeleteAll();
```

Restore the errors:

```
foreach (FormError er in SaveErrors)
   {
     string tempval = er.Site.Value;
     er.Site.SetValue(tempval);
   }
```

While this works with out fail for us in infopath, it on just some forms fails in sharepoint and I'm yet to figure out why, or how to work around it.

In sharepoint the restore method sometimes returns an exception when we try to set a value.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this would work 100% of the time in infopath but only work ~80% of the time in sharepoint?

Are there other approches to restoring validation?